# wordpress rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

trying to add a rewrite rule for wordpress site working but having no joy

```
function wptuts_add_rewrite_rules() {

add_rewrite_rule('^dukebox/([0-9-]*)/?','index.php?pagename=dukebox&startdate=$matches[1]','top');
flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'wptuts_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

what i want is for the

http://www.mikekeelin.co.uk/dukebox/?startdate=2013-02-25

to read

http://www.mikekeelin.co.uk/dukebox/2013-02-25

also have tried

```
index.php?p=85&startdate=$matches[1]','top');
```

but no joy

any help help greatly appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule is fine, try this line :

```
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'wptuts_add_rewrite_rules');
```

instead of adding yout rewrite rule at init :)

**EDIT :**

If this does not work, I think you should only call `add_rewrite_rule` function once, then call `flush_rules` to save them to the database, then you should be able to use your new url without any hook.